# page scrolling by clicking on add to cart button

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1

In the **Magento 2.3.1** on the **configurable** product detail page.

If **size/color** is not selected and clicking on add to cart the page is **scrolling** down.

**is this a good behavior?**

How can we stop scrolling in this case?

Comment: Is there any console error?

Comment: you should see a "This is a required field." message. Check your browser console for error messages.

Comment: there is no error in the browser console. the message 'This is a required field.' is displaying below the size thumbnails on the product detail page. the message is okay if we not select the size, but the page should not scroll down to the description tab when clicked on the add to cart button. please help on this.

Comment: This issue is fixed in Magento upgraded version 2.3.3

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 Methods of doing this.

**First Method:-**

You need to Override this file into your custom Theme.

*Core File :-*

> /vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation.js

*Overrided File :-*

> /app/design/frontend/[theme_vendor]/[theme]/web/mage/

then Delete/Comment the code on line **1961** in **Magento 2.3.2**

*From*

```
if (firstActive.length) {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: firstActive.offset().top
     });
     firstActive.focus();
}
```

*To*

```
if (firstActive.length) {                   
    firstActive.focus();
}
```

**Second Method:-**

Here is a solution with a mixin to avoid overwriting the whole file:

1) `app/design/frontend/[theme_vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Magento_Theme/js/lib/mage/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

2)`app/design/frontend/[theme_vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/web/js/lib/mage/validation-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.validation', widget, {
            /**
             * Handle form validation. Focus on first invalid form field.
             *
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             * @param {Object} validation
             */
            listenFormValidateHandler: function (event, validation) {
                let firstActive = $(validation.errorList[0].element || []),
                    lastActive = $(validation.findLastActive() ||
                        validation.errorList.length && validation.errorList[0].element || []),
                    parent, windowHeight, successList;

                if (lastActive.is(':hidden')) {
                    parent = lastActive.parent();
                    windowHeight = $(window).height();
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: parent.offset().top - windowHeight / 2
                    });
                }

                // ARIA (removing aria attributes if success)
                successList = validation.successList;

                if (successList.length) {
                    $.each(successList, function () {
                        $(this)
                            .removeAttr('aria-describedby')
                            .removeAttr('aria-invalid');
                    });
                }

                if (firstActive.length) {
                    /* vertically center the first field on the screen. This is best for UX but if you prefer to avoid the scrolling completelly, just remove the next line and the function "scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError" below. */
                    scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError(firstActive);
                    firstActive.focus();
                }
            }
        });

        function scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError(firstActive) {
            let fieldTop = firstActive.offset().top,
                fieldHeight = firstActive.height(),
                windowHeight = $(window).height(),
                offset;

            offset = fieldTop - ((windowHeight / 2) - (fieldHeight / 2));

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: offset
            });
        }

        return $.mage.validation;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Vishal's mixin solution raise the following JS error on Magento 2.4 :

`validation-mixin.js , line 9 : Uncaught TypeError: base is not a constructor`

I could solve this error by replacing :

`$.widget('mage.validation', widget, {`

by :

`$.widget('mage.validation', $.mage.validation, {`